# Define column name as a parameter with their cell value in R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

In my code i have defined parameters like:

```
Amazon <- "TRUE"
FlipCart <- "FALSE"
```

So whenever I need to change parameter flag or introduce new parameter, I needs to make those changes in code. So, instead of hard-coding parameters in code I have created a table with two columns as 'Parameter' and 'Flag' in which I can change flag value as well as insert new entry of Parameter in table.

For Example:
##I have created data frame to show example:

```
data <- data.frame(parameter = c("Amazon","Flipcart","JioMart","Dmart"),
                   flag = c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE")
)
```

##Take transpose to convert Parameter as column name and Flag as cell value:

```
datat <- tidyr::spread(data, parameter, flag)
```

I can automatically define parameter value using above data frame like:

```
Amazon <- data$Amazon
FlipCart <- data$FlipCart
```

Above approach is working when I change flag value of any parameter in table. But when I insert new Parameter in table I need to make code changes.
Like:

```
NewParameter <- data$NewParameter
```

Is there have any function/Logic which can automatically assign Parameter value even if I added new parameter in table.

Comment: why do you need to create multiple objects in the global env

Answer (score 0):

We could use `list2env` (not recommended)

```
tidyr::spread(data, parameter, flag) %>%
    unclass %>%
    list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Now, if we type

```
Amazon
#[1] "TRUE"
```

Comment: Thank you Arun for quick response, It's working for me.